# Is it possible to add a a variable within a placeholder transform in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I am looking to write an visual studio code user snippet like this:

```
 "Surround With Div": {
    "prefix": "sdiv",
    "body": ["${1/(.*)/<div class=\"${1}\">${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}<\\/div>/}"],
    "description": "Surround With Div"
  }
```

But it does not seem to be working. Is there any way I can make something like this work? Using the variable inside the result of the regex transform?

To clarify for people:

What I was trying to achieve is this:

Select a portion of html document

Type `sdiv` over it to get the snippet

write something like -> header for the class name...

then when I would hit TAB I would get a div with the class header and the content I first selected inside it

But I realized you can't do something like that...could have done it with $CLIPBOARD but had to copy it first

So I decided to do something a bit different using a keybinding instead.

Comment: this is a visual studio user snippet I created, but one part is not working. I know there are some quite knowdlegeable people here about visual studio code user snippet thats why I asked.

Comment: use `Emmet: Wrap with abbreviation` there is a single and a multicursor variant (I have no clue why) and fill in the next box `.thedivclass`

Comment: You should show the output you want.  It doesn't look like there is any need for the variable within the transform.

Comment: @Mark what I was trying to achieve is this...select a portion of html document, type sdiv over it to get the snippet, write something like -> header for the class name...then when I would hit TAB I would get a div with the class header and the content I first selected inside it...but I realized you can't do something like that...could have done it with CLIPBOARD but had to copy it first, so I decided to do something a bit different using a keybinding instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually more straightforward than it seems.  You do not need a transform at all - you can't put a variable like `$TM_SELECTED_TEXT` or `$CLIPBOARD` inside a transform anyway.

```
"Surround With Div": {
  "prefix": "sdiv",
  "body": [
    "<div class=\"${1}\">${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}</div>"],
  "description": "Surround With Div"
 }
```

[image: selected text snippet]

[image: selected text and emmet wrap demo]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222148/discussion-on-answer-by-mark-is-it-possible-to-add-a-a-variable-within-a-placeho).